# Getting error with function to check for set variables to propagate form fields

Tags: php, forms, variables, undefined

I am making a form that propagates field names if a certain condition is met with variables from a sql query and if that query doesn't happen it just leaves the fields blank.

I have a function that tests whether a checkbox is set, if it is then a query is ran and gets the values to put in the field, if it isn't I want the field to be blank but I keep getting an error message in the fields that the variable is not defined.

```
function AddEditValue($fieldName) {
global $edit_check_gtg;
if ($edit_check_gtg) {
echo $fieldName;
}
```

};

and this is the html that brings it into the field

```
Time:<input type="text" name="time" value="<?php AddEditValue("$field_time"); ?>"/><br>
```

I tried making a function to test if the variable is set using isset() but that doesn't work unless I write it out each time.

```
function AmISet($fieldName) {

if (isset($fieldName)) {
    echo "I am set";
}else{
    echo "I am not set";
}};
```

I just can figure out if there is another way to do this.  I know I could initalize the variables at the beginning and make them empty strings but I didn't know if there was a more concise check for these things within a function.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I saw `global` in that code. Argh, I got blinded!

Comment: put name attribute in `input` tag and use `$_GET['fieldname']` or `$_POST['fieldname']` or `$_REQUEST['fieldname']`

Comment: Your code does not reveal how you plan to fetch the request arguments value. You are probably looking for something like `isset($_GET[$fieldName])` or `isset($_POST[$fieldName])`...

Comment: What would you suggest using if not global?  I'm pretty new to this!

Comment: change `$fieldName` to `$fieldName == false` then do `if(FALSE !== $fieldName)`. Done.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy where in the function do you set $fieldname == false ?

Comment: here -> `function AddEditValue($fieldName = false) {`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work because it's looking for a variable that doesn't exist at that time.  Is there a way to set an undefined variable on fly so it doesn't return an error or do you have to initialize it outside of the function?